# Data does not export correctly using Get Data > From External Source > From Microsoft Query

Tags: excel, export-to-excel

I'm trying to export one column of data from one Excel sheet to another in the same workbook. I have done the same with several columns from the same pair of sheets. I have been using more or less the same query but I include it nonetheless:

```
SELECT dataForAZDHS.F38, dataForAZDHS.`0#023611111111`, dataForAZDHS.`0#036111111111`
FROM dataForAZDHS dataForAZDHS
WHERE (dataForAZDHS.PS='P') OR (dataForAZDHS.PS='F')
```

My original data is a time format, it's not even the only data formatted that way that I have exported using the same process/query. However, the result I'm getting returns a column with default values of date/time and not the values present in the column I'm taking the data from.

[original data of column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6aIk.png)

[result of importing data from other sheet in the same workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4Yue.png)

I don't know what I'm doing differently. The other queries are the same format, only the columns selected change. I've tried to change the format of the result but everything is a default value.

Comment: Is there any reasons you prefer the Microsoft Query over the Excel Connector? The Excel Connector might be more compatible to these formats. If supported you may try to specify the format in your SELECT?

Comment: … or connect to table/range as it is in the same workbook.

Comment: I wasn't aware of using excel connector as an option. I'm not very versed in Excel. I'll look into it, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, if it is within the same workbook, might be easier just to use cell function  (e.g. FILTER with PS matching P or F) , otherwise there is also a connector for table/range to get it into PowerQuery.